# Way to close specific output streams

Tags: java, stream, outputstream, zipoutputstream

Do you think this code close correctly the output stream entry ? Knowing that this is not the same type of output stream.

```
OutputStream out = new JarOutputStream(new FileInputstrem(fileName));
                       ...
((ZipOutputStream)out).closeEntry();
```

But considering that the both are output stream, I thought they were closing in the same way. And therefore in my case `((ZipOutputStream)out).closeEntry();` was the same as `((JarOutputStream)out).closeEntry();`

Can you confirm that if you think is true or correct me if is wrong ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to call methods that are specific to `ZipOutputStream` on your `out` variable, then its type should not be `OutputStream`, but `ZipOutputStream`:

```
ZipOutputStream out = new JarOutputStream(new FileInputstrem(fileName));
                   ...
out.closeEntry();
```

This doesn't cause any problem, because since `JarOutputStream` extends `ZipOutputStream`, a `JarOutputStream` is also a `ZipOutputStream` (and is also an `OutputStream`, and is also an `Object`).

Comment: Thanks I didn't know JarOutputStream was extends ZipOutputStream and it wasn't call methods specific to ZipOutputStream but juste create generic method to create Zip and Jar archive and use common method for close their output stream entry in this method. But now I know JarOutputStream inherits ZipOutputStream, this is easiest to implement. Thanks.

Comment: If `JarOutputStream` did not extend `ZipOutputStream`, then doing `(ZipOutputStream) out` would result in a `ClassCastException`.

Comment: Not necessarily because the close entry execute the same work for all output stream entry. And that's why I asked this question. I wasn't sure.

Answer (score 2):

Since `JarOutputStream` extends `ZipOutputStream`, and since all methods in Java are virtual, doing

```
((ZipOutputStream) out).closeEntry();
```

**calls the exact same method ass**

```
((JarOutputStream) out).closeEntry();
```

However, I'd suggest you make the static type a bit more precise:

```
ZipOutputStream out = new JarOutputStream(new FileInputstrem(fileName));
                   ...
out.closeEntry();
```

Answer (score 1):

> And therefore in my case ((ZipOutputStream)out).closeEntry(); was the
>   same as ((JarOutputStream)out).closeEntry();

That is correct. No reason to write the former whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

```
ZipOutputStream.closeEntry();
```

and

```
JarOutputStream.closeEntry();
```

both close the ZIP entry, so you can write another entry into the archive file (if you want to store more than one file into one ZIP/JAR). They do not close the output stream itself. If you want to close your JarOutputStream and the underlying FileOutputStream, use
    out.close();

Cf.:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipOutputStream.html#close()
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipOutputStream.html#closeEntry()